# Overflow text in Table row

Tags: html, css, overflow

Hi in my project I have a table which displays some large text.I have to show that text in line by line, that means I have to show all the text in the column.
I am giving the screenshot link below

[click for image](http://s6.postimg.org/cx08ob1k1/screen.png)

Comment: please post code on jsfiddle or post code snippet here itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```